# Include array with numeric keys fails

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have a weird problem when including a file.

The included file contains a log, and the contents is (exactly) like this:

```
<?php 
$fxe[20150518123308982711]='test 1';
$fxe[20150518123346582251]='test 2';
$fxe[20150518123545868736]='test 3';
```

The keys are made up from year+mont+day+hour+min+sec+random int

I expected, after including the file, `$fxe` to have 3 entries:

```
[20150518123308982711] => test 1
[20150518123346582251] => test 2
[20150518123545868736] => test 3
```

However, `$fxe` only contains 1 entry:

`[0] => test 3`.

The weird thing is, if - in the included file - I make the keys strings instead of numeric

```
<?php 
    $fxe['20150518123308982711']='test 1';
    $fxe['20150518123346582251']='test 2';
    $fxe['20150518123545868736']='test 3';
```

it correctly returns all 3 entries.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, your keys are greater than `PHP_INT_MAX`

Comment: Thanks. I never heard of that one. At least now I know why it's not working, and I switch back to strings.